# Why does this variable an empty sequence?

Tags: python, variables

The code i am using is selecting the highest number out of three in a text file set out as

```
R 3 5 7
F 2 9 6
I 6 3 5
```

When it is run it does wright the correct infomation to the text file but comes up with

```
 max_in_line = max(nums)
 ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence
```

my code is

```
with open (classno, 'r') as f, open("class11.txt", 'w') as fout:

      for line in f.readlines(): #does right swaps around
           if not line.strip(): continue
           parts = line.split()
           nums_str = line.split()[1:]
           nums = [int(n) for n in nums_str]
           max_in_line = max(nums)
           print (max_in_line)
           print (line)

           score = (max_in_line)#same problem
           name = (parts[0])
           fout.write(("\n") + str(score) + (" ") + (name))

      fout.close
      f.close#it does write them but comes up with the problem
```

Comment: Looks like you have a blank line... catch the exception and `print(line)`...

Comment: what do you mean by  this and what alterations are needed cheeers

Comment: Just try putting `if not line.strip(): continue` as the first line inside your for-loop - that's probably the easiest fix...

Comment: i printed the line and came up with what was in the text file but still comes up with the problem

Comment: i have just gotten rid of any lines but it is no saying that when i am writing it that list index is out of range

Comment: Are you deleting lines rather than ignoring them? If you delete elements from a list while iterating over it, it can/will cause problems.

Comment: i used the code jon clements but it comes up with list index is out of range when writing

Comment: @Richard well, that's going to be thrown by `names = (parts[0])` - did you put the line in that I suggested - it suggests you're still trying to process an empty line

Comment: when you say deleting what do you mean

Comment: yes i did i will update my code above to show what  i did with your line

Comment: You can remove `fout.close` and `f.close` at the end. You should be calling them eg: `fout.close()` and `f.close()`, but because you're using a `with` statement, the files will automatically be closed leaving the `with` block so they're redundant

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, just skip the empty line or empty element in the list:

```
with open ('classno.txt', 'r') as f, open("class11.txt", 'w') as fout:
  lines = [line.strip() for line in f]
  for line in lines:
    splitted = [i for i in line.split(' ') if i]
    nums = splitted[1:]
    max_nums = max(map(int, nums))
    name = splitted[0]
    fout.write('\n' + str(max_nums) + ' ' + name)
```

It works for me, hope helps.